# pandas dataframe group rows based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

I have a table that looks like this:

```
   P_id   S_id   Time
1  20     A    15 
2  30     B    50
3  50     A    99 
4  70     A    60
```

I want to group the table, based on the column "Sid", and sorted by Column "Time" so it will look like this:

```
     P_id       S_id   
1  20,70,50       A     
2    30           B
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where does the 99 come from in the P_id column of the result?

Comment: It should be `50` instead of `99` in P_id column of the expected output.

Comment: Use `df = df.sort_values('Time') .groupby('S_id', sort=False)['P_id'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. df here is the name of your data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S_id': ['A', 'B']})
df2.loc[:,'P_id'] = ''
for letter in df2.S_id.unique():
    indx = df2.loc[df2['S_id']==letter].index.values
    df1 = df.sort_values(by = ['S_id' ,'Time'])
    array_values = list(df1[df1.S_id ==letter].P_id.values)#.astype(object)
    df2.at[indx[0], 'P_id'] = array_values
df2
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the SQL query that generated that table? 
(Select P_ids, S_id, time from T)

Comment: @oren_isp , I am sure you can do it in SQL. Not sure your suggested command will work